# Trouble using ssh-key gen specifying location and password

Tags: linux, ssh, debian, bash, shell

This is my code:

```
ssh-keygen -t rsa -C "$APP"
```

This works perfectly. However it then asks me to specify location and password. I was hoping I can automate this all in one go, however this command fails:

```
ssh-keygen -t rsa -C "$APP" -P "$SSHKEYPASS" -T ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub
```

This command seems to fail though, when I specify the password I want for the key and location in the same line. I don't really understand the man page:

http://linux.die.net/man/1/ssh-keygen

Can anyone tell me where I have gone wrong?

Answer (score 2):

I had a go at this and the offender seems to be using the -T flag for output file path/name.
If you replace it with -f it does the trick (on ubuntu 14.04 here)

```
ssh-keygen -t rsa -C "$APP" -P "$SSHKEYPASS" -f ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub
```

Also noticed in the man pages just now that the `-P` flag you use for the passphrase is defined as 'old passphrase', and there is a switch `-N` to specify 'new passphrase'
The command succeeds with both though, anyone here knows the deal on these?

Note i did not test the key generated this way yet.